# Phalcon Migration ERROR: Wrong number of parameters

Tags: php, command-line-interface, phalcon

In phalcon 3 project I am trying to run my migrations and whenever I run cli command below:

```
bin/phalcon.php migration run --version=1.0.0 --migrations=migrations/
```

I am getting the warning below. It turns me crazy.

> ```
> Phalcon DevTools (3.0.1)
>
> ERROR: Wrong number of parameters
> ```

Really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like that is a general warning for lots of situation. For my case it turned out I have mistakes in my morph method.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. I used `phalcon migration run --version=1.0.0 --migrations=app/migrations/` in my project and it worked well. Latest phalcon with devtools 3.0.1. Maybe there is an error made in your migration files or they have been created long time ago and now are outdated. Try to regenerate them